# Create many documents

Tags: r, for-loop, report, r-markdown

I am using R studio Version 0.99.485. I have to do many reports based on one input vector, so I have decided to write for loop in R Markdown (R studio). I am giving only part of the code:

````
```{r forensis, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
load(file = "E:/data/R/Forensic_reports/fdata.RData")
for (i in 1:length(osobni_podaci$Oib)) {
  cat("  \n### UPIT ZA OIB: ", oibreq[i], '  \n')
  cat('  \n### STATUS OIB-A  \n')
  cat('Status: ',ifelse(oib_status$X_status[i] == 1, 'Aktivan', 'Neaktivan'), '  \n')
  cat('  \n### OSNOVNI PODACI  \n')
  cat("Ime: ", osobni_podaci$Ime[i], '  \n')
}
```
````

So, for every i in some vector, I am writing report with the same structure.

If I execute the code like this, it will return all reports in one document, but I would like to have as many html documents as reports.

**What do I need to add at the end of the for loop inside r chunk to save the report as document every time the loop is over?**

Comment: R creates a 'pdf/html,jpeg file' and start puting all the stuff in it unless it gets restared or told to make a new one. Like with figures you can do dev.off() or dev.next(). 
So I would suspect there to be something like that for Markdown, or just in general creating HTML files

Comment: @Jan Sila As I understand you, it is not possible to do multiple html documents from rmarkdown r chunk. I am not sure how should I embedded dev.off() or dev.next() into code.

Comment: I didn't mean exactly that, but something similar? I will try to google it when I get on my computer as well

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here: https://github.com/petrelharp/r-markdown-tutorial

With an .rmd like this:

````
---
title: "Visualization for `r input.file`"
date: "`r date()`"
---

```{r setup, echo=FALSE}
if (!file.exists(input.file)) { stop("Can't find file.") }
xy <- read.table(input.file)
```

The file `r input.file` 
has `r nrow(xy)` observations:

```{r plotit}
plot( height ~ age, col=type, data=xy )
legend( "topleft", pch=1, legend=levels(xy$type), col=1:nlevels(xy$type) )
```
````

an R script like this:

```
library(knitr)
owd <- setwd("examples/thedata")  # determines where output will go
opts_knit$set(root.dir=".")  # determines where code is evaluated
file.names <- list.files(".",".*tsv")
for (input.file in file.names) {
    output.file <- gsub(".tsv$",".viz.html",input.file)
    knit2html("../simple-template.Rmd", output=output.file, quiet=TRUE)
}
```

and a bunch of .tsv input files stored in the directory where the R script is evaluated.